# Xamarin ReactiveUI - You are referencing the Portable version of ReactiveUI in an App error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I've used a portable template to create a Xamarin app, and I have installed reactive UI into both the portable library and the Android library. However, when I deploy the app to my phone and cause a RaisePropertyChanged to be fired. I get the error:

> You are referencing the Portable version of ReactiveUI in an App.
>   Reference the platform-specific version.

I think I must be misunderstanding the level of compatibility with Xamarin. Do I need to create a shared project to use ReactiveUI?

Answer (score 1):

re: howdy

Don't think we have met, come join us in Slack https://reactiveui.net/slack !

re: problem

Check your references. It looks like `ReactiveUI` was not installed correctly into your Android application. The framework uses the `Bait & Switch` pattern - this error will happen is the switch is missing. You need to install `reactiveui` nuget package into your PCL/standard library AND platform application.

re: do you need to use shared?

Nope; PCL/netstandard works fine and thats my recommendation.

Comment: Hi, cheers for the input, I shall try this in a bit. Having a few issues with nuget packages right now, so I suspect I'm doing something else wrong too somewhere